# Create a scrollable table on a canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and I don't quite get it yet. I want to creat a scrollable table on a canvas using labels in a grid. I've seen some examples using the pack-manager which leads to even more chaos in my ui so I figured I'd rather stick with grid. However regardless of how many cells I choose the canvas and 
frame expand accordingly to display all cells hence leaving no scrollable region. How do I deal with this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def start_gui():
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.set_grid(20,4)
    main_window.root.mainloop()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, root = tk.Tk()):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Some Table')

        self.frame = tk.Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
        self.frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, width = 100, height = 100)
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, 0, 1000))
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.vbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, orient = 'vertical', command= self.canvas.yview)
        self.vbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'ns')

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.vbar.set)

    def set_grid(self, rows, columns):
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(columns):
                label = tk.Label(self.canvas, text = 'some label', relief = 'solid', width = 20)
                label.grid(row = i, column = j)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_gui()
```

Comment: to add to canvas use `canvas.create_window(..., window=label)` and remove `label.grid()` - or put Frame to Canvas (`create_window`) and then put Labels in Frame

Comment: @furas Thanks for your reply. I've seen that before and tried it. I really don't understand how to use create_window. It only played havoc on my ui and I don't know how to uniformly create a table with that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

You're not far away.  I've amended your code to make both Canvas and Scrollbar children of **root**. Frame is a child of canvas but is displayed as a Canvas window object, not by using grid.

A config callback is bound to a Frame configure event to set the Canvas scrollarea to be the Frame size as Frame changes size with it's contents.

```
import tkinter as tk

def start_gui():
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.set_grid(20,4)
    main_window.root.mainloop()

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, root = tk.Tk()):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Some Table')
        root.columnconfigure( 0, weight=1 ) # Stretch Column 0 to fit width.
        root.rowconfigure( 0, weight=1 ) # Stretch row 0 to fit height.

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'nsew')
        # Make canvas fit the whole of root. Useful to play with sizes.

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window( 0, 0, window = self.frame, anchor=tk.NW )
        # Makes frame an object in canvas

        self.vbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient = 'vertical', command= self.canvas.yview)
        # The scrollbar is a child of root.
        self.vbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'ns')

        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.vbar.set)

        self.frame.bind('<Configure>', self.on_config) 
        # Bind on_config to a Frame config event.

    def on_config( self, e ):
        # print(e.widget, e)
        # Set the canvas scrollregion to fit the whole of frame.
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, e.width, e.height))

    def set_grid(self, rows, columns):
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(columns):
                tk.Label(self.frame, text = str(i)+' : '+str(j), width = 20).grid(row = i, column = j)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_gui()
```

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I did that already. For some reason it's not working. Apologies. Ofcourse I'd like to give credit where it's due.

Comment: If you feel like you didn't get the credit you rightfully deserve I'm very sorry. For some reason this website doesn't allow me to upvote your comment. I also clicked on the anwser solved button and now I'm seeing it wasn't accepted. Maybe I didn't even tag you properly. Hope you're reading this. And thanks again